# Using awk for a bash script that defines a "minimum packages set"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I would like to write a script with the following requirements:

- in input, get a list of packages available via `apt`. In there you may have some packages that are automatically installed by other packages in list.
- in output, provide the same list without the packages that depends from other packages in list.

In other terms, I want to do in bash what [the user Francois G did in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58489/1037999)

Maybe something like this already exists, but sometimes I like to write scripts to improve my bash-scripting and also for fun.

In my mind, I already designed the script, but I have a technical issue. Let's assume that I have the dependency list in this format (it's the way `apt-rdepends` put it):

```
useless-line-1
useless-line-2
useless-line-3
item-1
  fixed-string substring-1-1
  fixed-string substring-1-2
  fixed-string substring-1-3
item-2
  fixed-string substring-2-1
  fixed-string substring-2-2
item-3
item-4
  fixed-string substring-4-1
  fixed-string substring-4-2
  fixed-string substring-4-3
  fixed-string substring-4-4
```

I want to extract the paragraph related to `item-1` i.e.:

```
  fixed-string substring-1-1
  fixed-string substring-1-2
  fixed-string substring-1-3
```

I'm not an `awk` expert, but I think that it can suit my purposes. I'm not able to "build" the correct command. Due to the fact that `item-2` may be not known, I tried:

```
# extract text between item-1 and the next line that starts without blank
$ awk '/item-1/,/^[A-Za-z0-9]/' deplist
item-1
```

but `item-1` already fits the condition `^[A-Za-z0-9]`, so it's not good. Moreover, I want to exclude `item-1` and `item-2` from the output.

Which is the best way to extract that portion of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something "stateful" ex.

```
$ awk -v item='item-1' '$0 !~ /^[[:blank:]]/{p=0} $0 ~ "^" item {p=1} p' deplist
item-1
  fixed-string substring-1-1
  fixed-string substring-1-2
  fixed-string substring-1-3
```

How this works:

- set `p=0` whenever we match a line that stars with anything other than horizontal whitespace (you could use your original slightly more specific `^[A-Za-z0-9]` here)
- set `p=1` if we match the desired `^item`
- print whenever `p==1`

Essentially "turn printing on when we match the desired item and turn it off when we match any other item".

You'll need a bit of extra logic to skip the matched line:

```
$ awk -v item='item-1' '
      $0 !~ /^[[:blank:]]/{p=0} {m = $0 ~ "^" item ? 1 : 0} m {p=1} p && !m
  ' deplist
  fixed-string substring-1-1
  fixed-string substring-1-2
  fixed-string substring-1-3
```

Here, we perform the same match but save the result in variable `m`; then set `p=1` when `m` is true (this part is identical to what we had before); we then only print when both `p==1` and `m==0` i.e. skip the line where the actual match occurs.

Comment: @LorenzKeel I've added some explanation - hope this helps